# How to change url of swagger.json on Azure Static Web App

Tags: azure-functions, swagger-ui, azure-static-web-app

I have an Azure Static Web app which is using an existing azure function as its [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/-web-apps/functions-bring-your-own) as per

This all worked ok, but if I try to view the swagger UI. i.e. /api/swagger/ui#/ on the static web app domain, it tries to load the swagger.json file from the azure functions original URL of the function which fails due to cors.

How can I change it to use the current domain?

Answer (score 0):

***Please check if the below steps helps to fix the issue:***

When you invoke the Azure Function API endpoint from the static web app site, all the  `CORS settings`  are set-up by default.

Accessing the API within the Azure static Web app using an external endpoint is not supported as discussed in this GitHub  [Issue](https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/108).

You can set the default domain in Azure static web app using the  [Custom Domains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/custom-domain-default#set-a-default-domain)  option.